# Deploy failed when develop a EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I am developing a simple stateful EJB. When deploy it, I get the error messages:

```
23:12:34,971 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.rar" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.rar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.rar\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.rar\"
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: org.jboss.jca.common.api.validator.ValidateException: IJ010075: The resource adapter metadata must contain either an outbound or inbound configuration
Caused by: org.jboss.jca.common.api.validator.ValidateException: IJ010075: The resource adapter metadata must contain either an outbound or inbound configuration"},
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.CartEJB.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.CartEJB]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.CartEJB.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.CartEJB]",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.rar\".batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.rar\".beanmanager]",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.rar\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.rar\".beanmanager]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.CartEJB.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.CartEJB]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.CartEJB.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.EJBTest2_ejb_exploded.CartEJB]"
]
}
```

What does it mean? It seems some dependency files are missing. What are they.

I appreciate for your help. :)

Comment: Why have you built your EJB into a RAR file?

Comment: @SteveC well, I'm new. Should I build it into a WAR file?or JAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create **WAR** or **JAR** package, not RAR (which is for resource archive).

If you are going to expose some web content (including REST webservices) use WAR package, if you are about to write only business logic use JAR packaging.

If project is under build control tool such as maven just change packaging node value, otherwise change should be made in IDE.